# I deleted my Flask database and added a new one now no database found on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I am building a simple flask app in gitpod. I am using ElephantSQL and deploying in Heroku. I am new to both platforms. I added my original database with one table and deployed my app - all seemed to function fine. I then decided to add user authentication in and instead of updating the table and migrating the changes under advice i deleted the original and added a new one. the new one has the same first table with the addition of one extra column and an extra table. I have pushed everything with Git and i now have no database showing in Heroku. I believe i should have updated the original tables and migrated those changes. Considering i have not done that what are my options. Do i still download flask migrate and migrate the changes despite it is a delete and re add or do i scratch my elephantSQL and Heroku app completely? Delete them and start a fresh? I have no data saved within the database so i am not at risk of loosing any stored data. Any advice would be really appreciated as this project is due in in one day and i am unsure of how to progress.

I have double checked the ElephantSQL URL in the configure vars and the GitHub connection and checked the database locally and all seems to be fine.

Comment: did you run ```db.create_all()``` to create the tables??

Comment: Yes i did, I tried it several times and still nothing

Comment: you can first use: ```export FLASK_APP=run.py``` for linux, or ```set FLASK_APP=run.py``` for windows. where run,py is the file from where your software starts. then you can use ```flask db init```, then ```flask db migrate``` and then ```flask db upgrade```. it first creates the migrations and then sets those migrations in the database. go through flask migrate documentation if you need help. i think this will resolve the problem.